# When I reboot my Ubuntu 22.04 VirtualBox, I have to set the screen resolution again. How do I make the resolution stick?

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome

I've installed a new Ubuntu 22.04 server with Gnome on a VirtualBox system and the size of the screen is reset to 800x600 on each reboot (both in the login screen and once logged in).

I change the screen resolution to say 1920x1600 and that works great. I can use the system for days without an issue.

The next time I reboot, though, that larger resolution is lost. It will be reset back to the 800x600.

Am I doing something wrong?

Note 1: I can see that the `~/.config/monitors.xml` is there and properly defined:

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>2</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>Virtual-1</connector>
          <vendor>unknown</vendor>
          <product>unknown</product>
          <serial>unknown</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1200</height>
          <rate>59.884601593017578</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Note 2: As mentioned in [a few places](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/224), I can copy the `monitors.xml` file to `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/.` and the Login screen works as expected. But once logged in, that resolution is lost again.

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/.
```

Note 3: I have other versions of Ubuntu (18.04, 20.04) with similar setups and the resolution sticks just fine.

Note 4: I have a single "monitor".

---

Updates:

When I run `xrandr --verbose`, I see modes such as this one:

```
1920x1440 (0x53b) 233.500MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
    h: width  1920 start 2064 end 2264 total 2608 skew    0 clock  89.53KHz
    v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1447 total 1493           clock  59.97Hz
```

I transformed that into a script like so:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1440_59.97"   233.50  1920 2064 2264 2608  1440 1443 1447 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 1920x1440_59.97
xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1920x1440_59.97
```

But the first and last `xrandr` generate errors:

```
$ sh xrandr1.sh
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  23
```

Now I've seen some people having issues with `XWAYLAND0`. Maybe that's what I'm running into...

---

Some logs found in the /var/log/syslog file:

```
Sep 15 23:31:47 ubuntu22 colord[2535]: failed to get edid data: EDID length is too small
Sep 15 23:31:47 ubuntu22 dbus-daemon[1214]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager'
Sep 15 23:31:47 ubuntu22 systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
Sep 15 23:31:47 ubuntu22 xbrlapi.desktop[2550]: openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
Sep 15 23:31:47 ubuntu22 xbrlapi.desktop[2550]: cannot connect to braille devices daemon brltty at :0
Sep 15 23:31:47 ubuntu22 /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session[2196]: dbus-daemon[2196]: [session uid=130 pid=2196] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
Sep 15 23:31:48 ubuntu22 gsd-color[2356]: failed to get edid: unable to get EDID for output
Sep 15 23:31:48 ubuntu22 gsd-color[2356]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual-1: unable to get EDID for output
Sep 17 01:10:40 ubuntu22 gnome-shell[2665]: XWAYLAND: mode 1024x600 is not available
Sep 17 01:16:20 ubuntu22 gnome-shell[2665]: message repeated 2 times: [ XWAYLAND: mode 1024x600 is not available]
```

The last one seems to indicate that by default the system expects a display named Virtual-1. Unfortunately, my display seems to be named XWAYLAND0 instead.

In that regard, I also found these:

```
Sep 16 02:36:12 ubuntu22 gnome-shell[2303]: Registering session with GDM
Sep 16 02:36:12 ubuntu22 gnome-shell[1764]: Connection to xwayland lost
Sep 16 02:36:12 ubuntu22 gnome-session[1742]: gnome-session-binary[1742]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Sep 16 02:36:12 ubuntu22 gnome-session-binary[1742]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
```

For that one, I can find a [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1966796).

I tried to turn off wayland but that did not help...

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

...in that the screen still comes up with the wrong resolution on a reboot. However, the `xrandr` command now works. If you'd like to make it work with Wayland, you may be able to use the [gnome-randr.py](https://gitlab.com/Oschowa/gnome-randr/-/tree/master/) script. Note that I did a reboot after changing the `WaylandEnable=false` (I think it goes without saying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "not elegant but works" category of fixes -

I faced this too with a VM that was a clone of a netbook with an odd screen size.  I couldn't get the VM to retain the screen size setting. So I wrote a script to resize the screen and added the script to the startup items.

In my case the script was

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x600_60.00"   49.00  1024 1072 1168 1312  600 603 613 624 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1024x600_60.00
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1024x600_60.00
```

Your values will likely differ.

Comment: Hmm... I get two errors, first when trying to create the `BadName (named color or font does not exist)` then another on the last `xrandr` command: `BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)`. Interestingly enough, if the resolution is already what I'm trying to set it as, then I get no errors!!! So the values are most certainly correct...

Comment: @AlexisWilke your numbers will be different. To create the "modeline" (the string of values in the `newmode` command, issue `cvt X Y Z` where X= desired width, Y=desired height, Z=desired Hz rate. Take everything after the word Modeline in the output and put it after the ---newmode in the first command

Comment: These are my numbers: `xrandr --newmode "1920x1440_59.97"   49.00  1920 2064 2264 2608  1440 1443 1447 1493 -hsync +vsync`. I took that from the output of `xrandr` with verbose. `1920x1440 (0x53b) 233.500MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2064 end 2264 total 2608 skew    0 clock  89.53KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1447 total 1493           clock  59.97Hz` (dreadful formatting here, let me add that to the question).

Comment: depending on what desktop you're using you may have a command like `lxrandr` or `arandr` that could be easier to use.

Comment: Neither of those are installed. I have the standard Ubuntu 22.04 desktop (i.e. what gets installed with: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`).

Comment: @AlexisWilke I saw your remark about wayland. If you are using that, all bets are off. I've never used it and I doubt xrandr works on it.

Comment: Okay! It worked! After I turned off the Wayland feature, the xrandr command works as expected. You have to wonder why they do things that way. Anyway. I'm good now!